# Can I make my app recognize the type of document my users have uploaded ?

Tags: attachment, content

This is not about using ContentType to identify the type of file (.pdf,.doc,.xls etc). This is about identifying which type of company form/document my user has uploaded. For instance, I have an app which manages our external partners. And for those partners we need such things as a govt Regulations Form or a Tax Form.

I would love to be able to identify which type of document a user has uploaded in order for the system to identify what has been obtained and what still needs to be gotten from the partner.

I was thinking that maybe creating multiple Notes & Attachment type of related lists which were specific to the type of forms (ie a Tax Form related list ; a Regulations related list) would do this since I could identify if any of those lists had anything in them. But I don't know if that's feasible.

The only other way I can think of possibly accomplishing this is to prompt the user to check a box indicating the type of document he is uploading. But that isn't really what I'm looking for.

Should I maybe be approaching this with Content instead of Attachments ?

Thank you very much for any feedback.

Comment: You may want to consider [a custom attachment object](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2014/05/30/how-to-customize-salesforce-attachments/) that gives you all the flexibility you need.

Comment: How exactly would you go about doing that ? Would you just have an object with one or two fields (used by the user to indicate the type of document) and a Notes & Attachment related list on that object ? And then run some WF to update the main document, indicating what's been filed ?

Comment: See above link.

Comment: @tobibeer - I think that's probably about as good of a solution as I'm going to get. Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question :
I am not sure , but can this be done ?!

*Read uploaded files content's* :

Let say you are aware that your 
Regulations Form : First Sentence = "My Regulation Form"
or a Tax Form : First Sentence = "This is a Tax form for the year..."

If yes then you can read your file contents by using something like this : 
(It works for .txt - see if it works for all other files )

```
    public PageReference readContent() {
    fileContent = fileBody.toString();
     /* your business logic : like here : Compare first line with 
         - accordingly use your business logic  
   */
   }
```

Comment: The file types mentioned in the question are .pdf,.doc,.xls which are all binary formats.

Comment: @Nilesh - that would probably be the only way to accomplish it in which the user would only have to upload the file and not have to indicate the type with a prompt (the solution by tobibeer above would require the user to indicate the document type themselves). But I don't see that working for myself because so many of the forms wouldn't have writing in the first line to differentiate. Thank you very much for the input though.